# Apache logging non-errors to error log

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache HTTPD 2.4 Windows is logging messages to it's error log - for example at startup:

```
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:38.106903 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2976:tid 628] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:40.011902 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2880:tid 552] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0h configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:40.012903 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2880:tid 552] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Mar 28 2018 12:38:12
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:40.012903 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2880:tid 552] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/apache -d D:/apache -f d:\\config\\apache\\httpd.conf'
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:40.017900 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2880:tid 552] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16368
[Wed Oct 23 15:15:41.213799 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16368:tid 488] AH00354: Child: Starting 30 worker threads.
```

Since we have a robust error monitoring this is causing false alarms. How can we get Apache to "behave"?

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l D:/log/errors/apache.errors.%Y%m%d.log 86400"
LogLevel error
```